# label field becomes clumsy during font setting

Tags: blackberry

I have an issue with Blackberry 5 & 6 Os on simulator
The label field becomes clumsy when i set the font 
the same runs fine in Blackberry 7

**here is my sample code**

```java
    LabelField _lblTitle3 = 
      new LabelField(offerStatus, 
                     USE_ALL_WIDTH | Field.FIELD_VCENTER |
                     LabelField.ELLIPSIS | Field.NON_FOCUSABLE) {

       protected void drawFocus(Graphics graphics, boolean on) {
       };

       protected void paintBackground(Graphics graphics) {
           String offerStatus = _offerObj.getCategoryStatus();

           int color;
           if (offerStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Saved"))
              color = Color.BLUE;
           else if (offerStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Accepted!"))
              color = Color.GREEN;
           else
              color = Color.BLACK;

           if (_isFocus) {
               graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
           } else {
               graphics.setColor(color);
           }

           super.paint(graphics);
       };
   };

   Font myFont = Font.getDefault();
   FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("Times New Roman");
   int fType = Font.BOLD
   int fSize = 12
   myFont = typeface.getFont(fType, fSize);
   _lblTitle3.setFont(myFont);
```

Image is below

[image: See the Field overlap]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What are you trying to do?  Just change the font color?**

If so, you probably don't want to override `paintBackground()`.

Inside your implementation of `paintBackground()`, you are calling `super.paint()`.  I'm not sure what that would do, but it wouldn't surprise me if that was wrong.

`paint()` and `paintBackground()` are two separate things.

If you just want to change the font color, depending on the text and the focus state, just put that logic in the `paint()` method, and leave `paintBackground()` alone (don't override it).

Also, when you change the `Graphics` context, to do things like set a new color, it's usually safer to store the old color first, and reset it later.  Something like this:

```java
        protected void paint(Graphics graphics) {
            int oldColor = graphics.getColor();

            String offerStatus = _offerObj.getCategoryStatus();
            int color;
            if (offerStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Saved"))
                color = Color.BLUE;
            else if (offerStatus.equalsIgnoreCase("Accepted!"))
                color = Color.GREEN;
            else
                color = Color.BLACK;

            if (_isFocus) {
                graphics.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            } else {
                graphics.setColor(color);
            }
            super.paint(graphics);

            graphics.setColor(oldColor);
        };
```